# Local IP not responding, while localhost and 127.0.0.1 does. Developing REST service in Python on Window 10 machine

Tags: python, windows, rest, pycharm

I’m trying to create a REST service on a Windows 10 PC using Python 3.9. My code responds appropriately when I make a request to localhost:5000 or 127.0.0.1:5000. The LAN address is 192.168.1.36 (Static), and if I ping that address I get a good response. I’ve created firewall rules for both inbound and outbound traffic at port 5000. When my code tries to access via the 192.168.1.36:5000 IP/Port I get a ‘refused to connect’ error. Further upstream I have my router setup to forward all port:5000 inbound traffic to 192.168.1.36. This doesn’t work, but is  expected since going directly to 192.168.1.36 also fails. Developing in PyCharm, and now trying to configure an In-place Server without success. Suggestions are welcomed!!

Comment: are you sure your rest service is listening on the 192 interface?

Comment: Really you need to share more details about your rest code, how you start it, how you define which interfaces it should listen on. Generally to have your web service listen on all interfaces you need to use 0.0.0.0 as the host

Comment: Thanks Chris, sounds like I need to go down that path next! First time trying to set up via PyCharm so crawling up the learning curve... thanks again!

Comment: are you using a framework like fastapi or django or something to produce your webservice? or coding it all from hand?

Comment: Figured it out, needed to set the host port on PyCharm/Flask configuration. Still crawling up the learning curve! Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!